# How do I attach an action to a UIPicker change?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

Im trying to update an UIImageView with a color based on data set in a UIPicker. 
How do I do it on the action of the Picker's data changing?

e.g., the user spins a component in the picker, and the change in data is automatically sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate method for the pickerView `– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` That gets called anytime the pickerView changes and it is where you would perform your "action" after a change.

Comment: It gets called once the scroll is complete... is there any way I can call something while the scroll is ongoing?

Comment: Think of it like this...as soon as the pickerView stops moving, that method gets called. I do not believe there is any way to call something while it is still scrolling. What is your purpose for wanting to do so?

Comment: I'm dealing with colors, so ideally when scrolling the PickerView, my imageView would show a gradual change in color, rather than the sudden jump of a completed scroll... thanks for your help though

Comment: I think you are trying to make it more complicated than it needs to be. If you want a gradual change, just use `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` and animate the transition in some fashion from your current color to the newly selected color. You can implement that method anyway you want.

Comment: You're right, im making it too complicated. I'll either do that, or I'll implement a timer to update the view every second or something, thanks

Comment: If you play with that delegate method, I think you will be surprised with the outcome. It is quite unlikely people will be scrolling the PickerView for more than a second without that delegate method being called.